# iframes' src overwriten when rendered recursively

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have some code that uses a recursive data model to create an iframe for each data item:

```
<div id="1">
  <iframe>
  <div id="1.1">
    <iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

For some reason, if the parent iframe src is set last (it's asynchronous), it also replaces the src of the children's iframes with its own. If it change it to a stacking model it works fine:

```
<div id="1">
  <iframe>
</div>
<div id="1.1">
  <iframe>
</div>
```

The code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/u3Aqk/2/. Open the JavaScript Console to see the invalid requests. (I intentionally used an invalid domain so that it would display in the console.)

You can toggle the two by changing which line is commented out. Note that the end of the lines differ from '$parent' to '$container'. If you set it to $container, you might have to run it a few times so that the parent loads last (if you get one or more '1-1' then that's the issue).

*Any ideas why passing the parent's container to the child causes the parent to own all iframes?*

The rest of the code shows why I'm setting the iframe src asynchronously.

HTML:

JavaScript:

```
console.log('-------- NEW TEST --------');
var content = [
    { 
        id: '1' 
        ,children: [
            {
                id: '1.1'
                ,children: []
            }
            ,{
                id: '1.2' 
                ,children: []
            }
        ]
    }
]

$contentTemplate = $('#content').remove();

contentMap = [];
for(var c=0; c<content.length; c++) {
    contentMap.push(new Content(content[c])); 
}

renderContent(contentMap[0].getContent());

function renderContent(content, $parentIn) {
    var $parent = $parentIn || $('#contents');
    var $container = $contentTemplate
            .clone()
            .attr('id', content.id)
    $container.find('.contentTitle').text(content.id);
    $parent.append($container);
    for(var cc=0; cc<content.children.length; cc++) {
        // This works, but the layout isn't what I want
        renderContent(content.children[cc], $parent);
        // This doesn't work, but the layout is correct
        //renderContent(content.children[cc], $container);
    }
    $.when(content.promise).then(function(data) {
        $container
            .find('.contentFrame')
            .attr('src', 'http://invalidurl.invalid/'+data+'-'+content.id);
    });
}

function Content(contentIn) {
    var id = contentIn.id
        ,children = [];    

    if(contentIn.children.length > 0) {
        for(var cc=0; cc<contentIn.children.length; cc++) {
            children.push(new Content(contentIn.children[cc]));
        }
    }

    function getId() {
        return id;
    }

    function getContent() {
        var deferred = $.Deferred();
        var content = {
            promise: deferred.promise()
            ,id: id
            ,children: []
        }
        if(children.length > 0) {
            for(var c=0; c<children.length; c++) {
                content.children.push(children[c].getContent());
            }
        }
        // in app, this loads HTML, not the json example
        $.ajax({
            url: '/echo/json/'
            ,success: function() {
                deferred.resolve(id);
            }
        });
        return content;
    }
    return {
        getContent: getContent
        ,getId: getId
    }
}
```

Comment: Please put the actual code in the question, as well.  Putting it in external websites devalues the original question and makes it more difficult for people to see the question and answer in the future.  A jsfiddle is great and appreciated, but should not be the only way to see the code.

Comment: I debated--even if it's long?

Comment: Yep!  Even if the code is long.  [Jon Skeet has a great post on how to write the perfect question.](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx)

Comment: On a side note, this many iFrames is clearly the work of a sith lord bent on corrupting the good nature of the DOM.

Comment: @BentOnCoding ...and yet, required. :(  It's a content management system, and I can't trust third-party content, and the third-party content requires assets that are relative after setting the iframe's content base. ...this is step one; down the road we'll begin to address all this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
$container
.find('.contentFrame')
.attr('src', 'http://invalidurl.invalid/'+data+'-'+content.id);
```

searches for all matching classes off of your cloned container. Try assigning unique id's to each iframe, and setting the url using the id as the selector.

Comment: *sigh* ...there goes this day.